# How to force child div to not overflow parent div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to overlay some text on a background in a Bootstrap3 site:

```
<div class="row  media-thumbs">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <div>
            <div class="thumb-overlay">Faculty</div>
            <a href="#">
            <img src="/default.png" class="pagethumb img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I add the css:

```
.thumb-overlay {position: absolute;width: 100%;}
```

it will expand wider than the immediate parent container, it appears to be trying to be 100% of the next parent up!

How do I fix this so it is only 100% of it's immediate parent?

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative` to the parent element, making the child absolutely positioned, relative to it.

```
.col-sm-3.col-xs-6 > div {
    position:relative;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/AF2AA/) - it works. Remove `position:relative` from the parent element, `.col-sm-3.col-xs-6 > div` to see the difference.

If you want to be more specific, use:

```
.row.media-thumbs .col-sm-3.col-xs-6 > div {
    position:relative;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/AF2AA/1/)

Comment: +1 Agreed. A little explanation: By default, `<div>` elements are `position:static`. To position a child element absolutely *relative to its parent*, the parent needs to be changed from the default `position:static` to `position:relative`.

Comment: @showdev Exactly, though it's a little strange, as boostrap adds `position:relative` to the `.col` classes.. I guess that wrapping `div` parent element makes all the difference.